# javascript layout/pattern/template for overall page scripts including jquery events, plugin config, etc

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Is there a standard layout/pattern for the main javascript behind a page?

Including:

- defining config for plugins used in the page
- initializing plugins on form elements
- defining elements - e.g. form = $('#form1')
- binding events to elements
- initializing modules in other javascript files

I use the module pattern for.. well, modules but this isn't a module. it's the main page that references the page elements and the modules

Comment: Here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/  and here: http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

Comment: well that's definitely a list of patterns, but it's not an answer

Comment: Yes @Sam. That's why it is a comment. Just to get you started.